# how to let a windows machine not discoverable on a network?

Tags: windows, networking

i have a network with my neighbors.
so i want to let my machine not discoverable.
how can i do this?
by not discoverable i mean that when they click on my neighborhood they dont find it.
i know that by accessing my IP address they will be always able to see it.
but they are not so technically aware.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable LLTD on your interface.

Hide your server. In elevated cmd type:

```
 net config server /hidden:yes
```

Comment: well i issued the command but i still can see the computer, i think this command takes some time to be active

Comment: Have you disabled Link Layer Topology Discovery on interface?

Comment: it worked now. i guess it just needed some time so that the other pcs forget the pc they saw before :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Vista or 7, there is an option in [Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.winvistaclub.com/Ultimate_Windows_Tweaker.html) to "hide" your computer from Network Neighbourhood.

I think for XP you can do with with [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx), although nenver needed so so I'm not sure.

Comment: you dont know which rules to configure in tweakui ? since i didnt find anything there :(

Comment: afraid not, I was under the impression that TweakUI would have done what you wanted. Seems to be more interface-only though (hence the name). Try Casual Coders answer.

Answer (score 0):

put your PC to another work group different as your neighbors has

Its enough to computer been "invisible" from my neighborhood.

As permanent solution install personal firewall to your PC

Comment: this is not a good solution as you can open "Entire Network" frm "My Network Places" And you will see this different neighborhood. u dont need to be a savy user to know this.

Comment: as the firewall solution , its actually good one but i think this is too much hassle for me to configure all the rules and stuff.